# Displaying Text in Randomly Sorted Array: Adobe ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting

My goal is to randomly sort an array and to display the sorted information in a text box. Simple enough, I would think (but not so simple for someone such as myself, unfortunately). Anyway, here's what I have:

```
var words:Array = ["word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 4", "word 5"];

function randomize ( a : *, b : * ) : int {
    return ( Math.random() > .5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}

trace( words.sort( randomize ) );

txtWordDisplay.text = words
```

When I run this code, I get the error message: "Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type String." When I pursued this error, I found further "clarification":

> You are attempting to cast an object to a type to which it cannot be
>   converted. This can happen if the class you are casting to is not in
>   the inheritance chain of the object being cast.

However, I'm not quite sure what to make of that.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: txtWordDisplay.text = words -> .text expects an instace of String, gets and instance of Array (words). :) You should use txtWordDisplay.text = words.toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TextField [`text`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#text) property cannot implicitly convert an array of strings to a single string, which it is expecting.

It works from your trace because [`trace`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#trace()) accepts an array of arguments:

```
public function trace(... arguments):void
```

If you want similar behavior, as in a comma delimited string, you could call `toString()` on the array:

```
txtWordDisplay.text = words.toString();
```

Otherwise, loop over your array and build a string:

```
words = words.sort(randomize);
var sentence:String = "";

for (var i:uint = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    // Capitalize first word.
    if (i == 0) {
        sentence += words[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
        sentence += words[i].substr(1, words[i].length);
    } else {
        sentence += words[i];
    }

    // Add space between words or punctuation.
    if (i < words.length - 1)
        sentence += " ";
    else
        sentence += ".";
}

txtWordDisplay.text = sentence;
```

This would output:

> Word 5 word 3 word 1 word 4 word 2.

Answer (score 0):

This works (without casting):

```
var words:Array = ["word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 4", "word 5"];
txtWordDisplay.text = words.sort(function():int {return(Math.random() > .5 ? -1 : 1)});
```

or by changing the way you call your function:

```
txtWordDisplay.text = words.sort(randomize);
```